# How to calculate the number of all possible combinations for a range of numbers from 1 to N?

Tags: python, math, combinations, python-itertools

Other than doing this:

```
from itertools import combinations
def brute_force(x):
    for l in range (1,len(x)+1):
        for f in list(combinations(range(0,len(x)),l)):
            yield f
x = range(1,18)
len(list(brute_force(x)))
```

[out]:

```
131071
```

- **How could I mathematically calculate the number of all possible combinations?**
- **Is there a way to do it computationally without enumerating the possible combinations?**

Comment: [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations): *The number of items returned is n! / r! / (n-r)! when 0 <= r <= n or zero when r > n.* Why do you convert `combinations(range(0,len(x)),l)` to `list` anyway?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Always there is **2<sup>n</sup>−1** non-empty subset of set `{1,...,n}`.

For example consider the list `['a','b','c']`:

```
>>> [list(combinations(['a','b','c'],i)) for i in range(1,4)]
[[('a',), ('b',), ('c',)], [('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('b', 'c')], [('a', 'b', 'c')]]
>>> l=[list(combinations(['a','b','c'],i)) for i in range(1,4)]
>>> sum(map(len,l))
7
```

That the length of our list is 3 so we have 2<sup>3</sup>-1=7 combinations.

And for a `range(10)` :

```
>>> l=[list(combinations(range(10),i)) for i in range(1,11)]
>>> sum(map(len,l))
1023      #2^10-1 = 1024-1=1023
```

Note if you want to count the empty subset you can just use `2^n`.

Actually at a mathematical perspective :

> a k-combination of a set is a subset of k distinct elements of S. If the set has n elements, the number of k-combinations is equal to the [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) :

[image]

and for all combinations :

[image]

Comment: Note to downvoters: this is the correct answer. The OP isn't just generating combinations of a fixed size, but summing over *all* combinations. (That is, not just choose(n, k), but sum(choose(n,k), k=1..n)).

Comment: Why the "-1" though? What crime has the empty set done to you? ;)

Comment: Yeah, just kidding. You may want to link to the [Binomial Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) page in Wikipedia. We can substitute x=1 and y=1 and easily prove that `2^n = comb(n,0) + comb(n,1) + ... comb(n,n)`

Comment: @ypercube ;), I was doing that! fixed!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a list from `[1, 10)`, and you want to choose `3` items

Mathematically

```
>>> math.factorial(9) // (math.factorial(3) * math.factorial(6))
84
```

This is the definition of [combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination)

```
_____n!_____
 k!(n - k)!
```

So as a general function

```
def num_combinations(n, k):
    return math.factorial(n) // (math.factorial(k), math.factorial(n-k))
```

Brute force

```
>>> len(list(itertools.combinations(range(1,10), 3)))
84
```

Comment: You probably want to use `//` rather than `/`, else you'll get incorrect results on Python 3.